# Populating a nested dictionary with a simple list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a `list = [1,2,3,4,5]` which I want to populate into a dictionary but my dict is currently
`my_dict={a:none,b:[none,none,none],c:none}`

Required output: `{a: 1, b: [2,3,4], c: 5}`

Comment: What is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_dict = {'a': None,'b': [None, None, None],'c': None}
for key in my_dict.keys():
    if my_dict[key] == None:
        my_dict[key] = my_list[0]
        my_list.pop(0)
    else:
        if type(my_dict[key]) is list:
            for item in range(len(my_dict[key])):
                if my_dict[key][item] == None:
                    my_dict[key][item] = my_list[0]
                    my_list.pop(0)
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
 {'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3, 4], 'c': 5}
```

Comment: you can also add raise exception in condition for not to exhaust your list.

Answer (score 0):

This code segment assigns the first element to `a`, the last element to `c`, and all intermediate elements are assigned to `b`.

```
lis = [1,2,3,4,5]
output = {'a': lis[0], 'b': lis[1:len(lis)-1], 'c': lis[len(lis)-1]}
print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3, 4], 'c': 5}
```